# Pandas select the maximum values from certain column group by labels

Tags: python, pandas

Here is what my dataset looks like:

```
dateCreated vehicleType     price   dailyPriceByType
0   2015-08-10  cabrio      5200      5200
1   2015-09-09  kleinwagen  9500      9500
2   2015-11-10  limousine   5499      5499
3   2015-12-05  limousine   900       900
4   2015-12-30  limousine   2400      2400
...
49194   2016-04-07  limousine 1500  1282599
49195   2016-04-07  cabrio   5900   72597
```

I want to find the rows contain the largest values from the column 'dailyPriceByType' for each type of the vehicle. In SQL, i can do this by:

```
select *
from table
group by vehicleType
having max(dailyPriceByType)
```

But how can i achieve this in python using pandas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('vehicleType')['dailyPriceByType'].max().reset_index()
```